# I want to remove an element but the click () does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to click `.close` to remove `.status-profile` but `click()` does not work.
I think the problem may be a class close to be within the class status-profile.

my html:

```
<div class="status-profile">
<div class="message">
    <span>You should complete your <b>profile.</b></span>
</div>
<div class="close">
    <i class="icon-cancel"></i>
</div>
<div id="bar" class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{res}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {res}%">
    </div>
</div>
```

my js:

```
$('.status-profile .close').click(function()
    {
        console.log("close");
        status = 100;
        $(".status-profile").remove();
    });
```

thanks to all

Problem solved:
the problem was that the html is loaded trough ajax call and the class close was not yet in the DOM ... thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Is the element on the page when you attach the click event?

Comment: make sure when your script is executed the close button is there in the dom

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5N54t/1/

Comment: thanks Arun P Johny. the problem was that the html is loaded trough ajax call and the class close was not yet in the DOM ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to subscribe to click event in document.ready:

```
$(function(){
    $('.status-profile .close').click(function(){
        console.log("close");
        status = 100;
        $(".status-profile").remove();
    });  
});
```

Click on "Close":

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mM7f/)

Comment: What do you mean with "first" ?

Comment: before the click event is triggered.

Comment: I've tried this way and as a function but does not work

Comment: I'll prepaire a jsfiddle

Comment: I've added the demo. I used a simple div instead icon.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the exact HTML that you're using? If so, the

```
<div class="status-profile">
```

is missing its closing tag which would prevent jQuery from working as you'd expect.

Add another

```
</div>
```

right at the end and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

when the js code execute the dom doesn`t prepare and $('.status-profile div.close') can`t find and element
$(document).ready(function(){
    dosometh
})